# Chat room restrictions

Tags: support

What are the restrictions on editing and deleting messages in the chat rooms? The first time I tried it the options were there, but they went way.

Answer (score 1):

**You can only edit or delete your message within 2 minutes.**

According to the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#talk),

> #### How do I talk?
>
> If you make a mistake when entering a message, press the <kbd>↑</kbd> up arrow to edit your last message … or press <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel editing. **You have 120 seconds to edit your messages.** All edited messages have a small edit indicator.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

That restriction also applies when deleting messages, and also for regular users and even Room Owners. Only moderators and SE staffs can bypass this restriction; editing/deleting anyone's messages at any time.